# Is there a software or web service that allows the creation of basic flow charts from text (such as a numbered or bulleted list)?

Tags: charts, flowchart

I know of many high quality flow charting tools, online and off, but is there any that allows the very rapid creation of a flow chart, however simple, from text? I want a way to bypass all the initial shape movement and rigmarole and dive straight into the flow; I want to worry about editing and formatting and dragging around shapes *after* I've laid the basic groundwork.

Example: Let's say I want a quick flow chart mock up. I'd love to be able to enter the below and have a simple one made; (3 is a decision tree in some hypothetical format)

1. contact customer
2. record customer issue
3. nature of issue?

   a. issue is technical

   3a. pass to tech support department

   b. issue is service-related

   3b. pass to customer support
4. fin

Comment: You can do this (to some extant) in Word by inserting SmartArt.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using http://yUML.me for this sort of thing:

For example code like this:

```
// Cool Class Diagram
[Customer|-forname:string;surname:string|doShiz()]<>-orders*>[Order]
[Order]++-0..*>[LineItem]
[Order]-[note:Aggregate root{bg:wheat}]
```

will yield a flow chart like this:

[image]

It's fully text based, and you can even use the text to make a link like:

`http://yuml.me/diagram/plain/class/edit/%2F%2F Cool Class Diagram, [Customer|-forname:string;surname:string|doShiz()]<>-orders*>[Order], [Order]++-0..*>[LineItem], [Order]-[note:Aggregate root{bg:wheat}]`

*Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with yUML.me*